# Solidify not even on plane rotation

Tags: modeling

I'm a noob in Blender and trying to figure out how to make a box packaging. I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qkj1okN4ZqQ&t=940s

My problem is when I apply a "Solidify" modifier to the plane and rotate a part of the box, the solidify modifier it's not even. I'm sure that I'm missing something. Can you help?

Here is a preview:
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In object mode, try to select *Object > Apply > Scale*. Do not forget to select *Even Thickness* in Solidify Modifier.